Multiprocessing pickle error with emcee in a class
I am writting a class object to perform an MCMC with the emcee package in python. The data is loaded from numpy files (either npz or npy) in a seperate class called sim (simulations). Inside the MCMC class I have a function called run_mcmc with a flag for multiprocessing. If false, the emcee sampler runs as expected, but when I add a "pool" argument to  emcee.EnsembleSampler I get the following error:
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object
Or similar errors that internal functions cannot be pickled.
Here is a shortened version of my class:
class squashed_mcmc:
    def __init__(self, Galaxy_ID, data_path):
        self.Galaxy_ID = Galaxy_ID
        self.data_path = data_path
        self.simulations = sim.fit(Galaxy_ID, data_path)
        self.data = self.simulations.smoothed_data
        self.data_dict = {key: self.data[key].copy() for key in self.data.files}
        self.data.close()


    def chi_squared(self, model, frac_err=0.1,n=1,r0=10,rmin=0,rmax=1e10):
        **removed**
        return log_likelihood

    def particles_per_pixel_theory(self, model):
        **removed**
        return output
    
    def mass_per_pixel_data(self):
        **removed**
        return mass_per_pixel_data


    ################# MCMC Functions ####################
    #####################################################
    # Define the model on which to run the MCMC 
    def model(self, theta, **kwargs):     
        # Unpack the parameters
        rm, c, q0 = theta
    
        # Define the squashed Jeans model
        model = self.simulations.squashed(r1=rm, c=c, q0=q0, **kwargs)

        return model
 
    def likelihood(self, theta, **kwargs):
        # Create the profile from the model  
        profile = self.model(theta, **kwargs)
        
        if profile is None:
            return -np.inf, None
        
        # Calculate the likelihood 
        chi_squared = self.chi_squared(profile)
        cross_section = profile.cross_section()
        
        return chi_squared, cross_section

    def lnprior(self, theta):
        **removed**
        if priors:    
            return 0.0 
        else:
            return -np.inf

    def lnprob(self, theta, **kwargs):
        lp = self.lnprior(theta)
        if not np.isfinite(lp):
            return -np.inf, None
        
        likelihood, cross_section = self.likelihood(theta, **kwargs)
        if not np.isfinite(likelihood):
            return -np.inf, None 

        return lp + likelihood, cross_section
    
    #################### Run MCMC #######################
    #####################################################
    def run_emcee(self, theta, nwalkers=20, niter=100, initial_volume=1e-3, multiprocessing=False, save=False, filename=None, relaxation_kwargs=None, emcee_kwargs=None):
        **removed file saving code**

        # Set up the initial conditions for the walkers
        initial = np.array(theta)
        ndim = len(theta)

        p0 = [initial + initial_volume*np.random.randn(ndim) for i in range(nwalkers)]

        # Boolean checking if the file already exists
        resume = os.path.exists(filename)

        if multiprocessing:
            with mp.Pool() as pool:
                if save:
                    print(filename)
                    backend = emcee.backends.HDFBackend(filename)
                    if resume:
                        print("Continuing previous run...")
                        p0 = None
                    else:
                        print("Setting up new backend...")
                        backend.reset(nwalkers, ndim)
                    sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, self.lnprob, kwargs=relaxation_kwargs, pool=pool, backend=backend, **emcee_kwargs)
                else:
                    sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, self.lnprob, kwargs=relaxation_kwargs, pool=pool, **emcee_kwargs)

                print("Running production with multiprocessing...")
                pos, prob, state, blob = sampler.run_mcmc(p0, niter, progress=True)
        else:
            **removed**

            print("Running production...")
            pos, prob, state, blob = sampler.run_mcmc(p0, niter, progress=True)


        return sampler, pos, prob, state, blob


Removed all nested anonymous function that were causing pickle issues
Tried closing data instance from sim (implemented in init)
Tried changing default pickle to dill
Tried externally pickling functions/classes to see what function specifically was causing the issue
Removed run_emcee from class structure (same error)

My guess is that the data from the sim class is not pickalable, but I have not seen this specific error on stackoverflow, i.e. _io.BufferedReader.

I tried using pathos.multiprocessing as in this post and got the following error PicklingError: Can't pickle 'BagObj' object: <numpy.lib.npyio.BagObj object at 0x1677f4090>
